# Making a structure in class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am making my first steps in learning OOP . And here is the first problem which I can't solve.
The max function in this class should return the maximum of two numbers . I want to keep the numbers in the private scope and the functions in the public scope . But when I want to use variables from `struct data{}` in the public scope the compiler says that the variables are not declared . Please tell me why I get these errors .

```
class myclass{
private:
   struct data{
       int q ;
       int w;
   };

public:
   void get(int a, int b){
      struct data = {a , b}; // here I want to pass the variables to data struct
   }
   int max (){              // this function returns the biggest number 
      if(q>w)
         return q;
         else 
            return w;
   } 

};
```

Comment: Why are you doing this with a class at all? A function template would be more appropriate, I would think. Regardless you need an *instance* of your `data` struct as a member variable of `myclass`; not as a local scope variable of the `get()` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609372/how-do-i-declare-a-struct-within-a-class

Comment: ... or of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930296/accessing-member-of-structure-within-a-class/16930355#16930355 ...

Comment: I am doing it with classes only to see and understand how it works . I know it can be written with one line :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ "class" and "struct" are close to being synonymous (the same thing). The ONLY difference is that a "struct" defaults to being "public" accessibility while a "class" defaults to private.

Once you understand this, it should become obvious that what you are doing is defining a sub-type within your class.

```
class myclass {
private: // <- not required, you already said that by saying "class".
    struct data {
        // <-- this is a class definition with "public:" just here.
        ...
    };
};
```

C++ allows you to nest class/structure definitions so that you can, for example, create structures that marshal parameters or return values.

```
class Database {
    class Result { ... };
};

...

class Exam {
    class Result { ... };
};
```

These two result classes avoid namespace collision, by being Database::Result and Exam::Result instead of just "Result".

However - these are only definitions. They do not - as shown - have any effect on the outlying class, that is: they aren't being used to add a member to the class.

Your code:

```
class myclass{
private:
   struct data{  // <-- this is a TYPE declaration, struct myclass::data
       int q ;   //
       int w;    // 
   };            // <-- no member name here so does not affect myclass itself.

public:
   void get(int a, int b){
      struct data = {a , b}; // here I want to pass the variables to data struct
   }
   int max (){              // this function returns the biggest number 
      if(q>w)
         return q;
         else
            return w;
   }

};
```

Declares a type "myclass::data" but does not add a member of type "myclass::data" to the class. The line "struct data = " is illegal, you're trying to assign values to a TYPE.

It should probably be written as

```
class MyClass {
    int m_q;
    int m_w;

public:
    void set(int q, int w) {
        m_q = q;
        m_w = w;
    }

    int max() const {
        return (m_q > m_w) ? m_q : m_w;
        // or #include <algorithm> and return std::max(m_q, m_w);
    }
};
```

You only need to hoist q & w into a struct if you are going to reuse that structural definition outside the confines of the class, e.g. in derived or parallel classes where you may want to add more of the same *type of thing*, in which case, you could perhaps do the following, but if you do it *this* exact way you'll eventually kick yourself for breaking encapsulation:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    struct Data {
        int m_q;
        int m_w;
    };

private:
    Data m_data;

    void set(int q, int w) {
        m_data.m_q = q;
        m_data.m_w = w;
    }

    int max() const {
        return (m_data.m_q > m_data.m_w) ? m_data.m_q : m_data.m_w;
    }
};
```

A better way, if this coupling of members needs to be externally visible to some degree would be:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    class Data {
        int m_q;
        int m_w;
    public:
        Data() : m_q(0), m_w(0) {}
        Data(int q, int w) : m_q(0), m_w(0) {}

        void set(int q, int w) {
            m_q = w;
            m_w = w;
        }

        int q() const { return m_q; }
        int w() const { return m_w; }

        int max() const { return (m_q > m_w) ? m_q : m_w;
    };

private:
    Data m_data;

public:
    MyClass() : m_data() {} // or = default
    MyClass(int q, int w) : m_data(q, w) {}
    MyClass(const Data& data) : m_data(data) {}

    // Read-only access
    const Data& data() const { return m_data; }
    // To allow write access, e.g. for set:
    Data& data() { return m_data; }
};
```

It's kinda overkill for such a simple case, but welcome to C++: the boilerplate language.

Comment: np - fixed a few typos etc - hope they clarify

Answer (score 5):

```
struct data{
    int q ;
    int w;
};
```

only declares a *type*, not an *object*, so there are no `q` and `w` members anywhere inside your `class` instances. You need the declare an *instance* of the `struct`:

```
struct {
     int q;
     int w;
} data;
```

Then, you can write `max` as:

```
int max()
{
    if (data.q > data.w)
        return data.q;
    else 
        return data.w;
}
```

(I've no idea what your `get` method is supposed to do, so I have no replacement for that.)

Comment: `get` looks like it should be named `set` instead ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the structure but there is no object of that type. You should declare an object and you will not get any error.

```
class myclass{
private:
   struct data{
       int q ;
       int w;
   }var;

public:
   void get(int a, int b){
     var .q= a;
    var.w=b; // here I want to pass the variables to data struct
   }
   int max (){              // this function returns the biggest number 
      if(var.q>var.w)
         return var.q;
         else 
            return var.w;
   } 

};
```